# Wordpress intercept saving attachment details

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, media-library

I am running version 4.5.3. When user edits caption / title (while inserting a media in the post) I want to execute certain action like process them before writing the caption/title to the database. However, I am not sure which DOM event I should override for this. I tried using Chrome monitorEvents, still can't find. Or is there a better approach?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't do anything with the DOM events, you should most likely be hooking in to some built in Wordpress functionality, like the `send_to_editor` function, or modifying the data on the backend before it's written to the db with one of Wordpress' many builtins.

Comment: could not find much documentation on how I can use send_to_editor for this purpose. Not even sure where to find the hooks. In case if you have more information would like to know more